# plot Mapped SNP on chromosome?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried to draw a plot like attached 'Mapsnp: An R Package to Plot a Genomic Map for Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms'. I couldn't install the packages in R, I would like to know is there any alternative way? [image]

```
File A:

GeneA   chr2  100   200


File B:

rs12   chr2    50   51
rs23   chr2    201  202
rs34   chr2    105  106



>install.packages("mapsnp")
Installing package into ‘/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu- 
library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘mapsnp’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)

> library("devtools")
Loading required package: usethis
> install_github("csuzfq/mapsnp_pkg/mapsnp")
Downloading GitHub repo csuzfq/mapsnp_pkg@master
Skipping 2 packages not available: Gviz, 
TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpT9p596/remotes341269c2a94b/csuzfq- 
mapsnp_pkg-cb6c8bf/mapsnp/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘mapsnp’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
   Warning in file(con, "r") :
     cannot open file 'man': No such file or directory
    ERROR
   computing Rd index failed:cannot open the connection
Error: Failed to install 'mapsnp' from GitHub:
  System command error, exit status: 1, stderr:
E> Warning in file(con, "r") :
E>   cannot open file 'man': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Plaese share the error message that you get when trying to install `Mapsnp`

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post.

Comment: Try to download this zip file https://filebin.net/2s291stqflqwkzbh and install it using `Packages -> Installa packages from local file`. then type `library(mapsnp)` and try the example `data(snp)` and `msa(M=snp,start=111950277,end=112036294)`.

Comment: Aren't the dependencies of `mapsnp` Bioconductor packages that you should download from Bioconductor? At least, `TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knowngene` is definitely a Bioconductor package.