# how to install mapsnp in R?

Tags: r, installation, package

I tried to install "mapsnp" in R.
I tried to run the same script like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494302/plot-mapped-snp-on-chromosome).

however, it did not work. I also run like this

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)) + install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Gviz")
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene")
install.packages("~/mapsnp_pkg-master/mapsnp_0.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

still did not work. in my R console, it was written like this

```html
> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)) 
+   install.packages("BiocManager")
> BiocManager::install("Gviz")
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.13 (BiocManager 1.30.16), R 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
  path: C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.0/library
  packages:
    lattice, Matrix, mgcv, nlme, survival
Old packages: 'cpp11', 'data.table', 'digest', 'ggsignif', 'hms', 'knitr', 'lifecycle', 'maptools', 'matrixStats', 'mime', 'openssl',
  'pillar', 'psych', 'R6', 'RcppArmadillo', 'readr', 'remotes', 'rmarkdown', 'stringi', 'tibble', 'tidyr', 'tinytex', 'vroom', 'xfun'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:   install.packages("BiocManager")
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: BiocManager::install("TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene")
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: install.packages("~/mapsnp_pkg-master/mapsnp_0.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
library(mapsnp)
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
library(mapsnp)
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:
```

I do not know what's wrong. Every time, if I want to type something after running the script above, it will be displayed "update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:"

Anyone can help me what was wrong?

Comment: And what happened? Just saying "did not work" isn't that useful for anyone trying to help you

Comment: I have edited my post. The problem is the script did not work. I need someone's help to tell me or help me to fix this

Comment: Did you check this from the error: `Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages`. Are you admin? Have you used "Run as administrator"?

Comment: I understand, Thank you